# How to tackle emails failed to send after commit database php

Tags: php, html-email, email-validation

The case is I am calling a function which makes changes in DB and return list of users to whom I have to send emails.
If my db have made changes and selected users and due to some reason emails were not send and users are not informed from changes.
How to make sure that emails were sent after making changes in DB and if emails were failed to send what action should be taken.

Comment: Always check if your email was sent successfully and then update the db if so. Write some extra code to do this, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysqli transaction commit & rollback when fails

here is another thread that may help you

[Mysql transaction : commit and rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890966/mysql-transaction-commit-and-rollback)

Answer (score 0):

You should restructure your code in order to SELECT the users you wanted to update, try to email, and update the successfully emailed contacts. Maybe add a flag to denote contacts that had a successful email.

This way on your next SELECT you will have the left over ones that failed to email and were not updated.