# What is the difference (in MySQL) between transaction-rollback and not commiting?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, transactions

I have a question regarding MySQL and transactions. I work with MySQL 5.7.18, python 3 and the Oracle mysql connector v2.1.4

I do not understand the difference between 
a) having a transaction and –in case of error – rollback and 
b) not having a transaction and – in case of error – simply not commiting the changes.

Both seem to leave me with exactly the same results (i.e. no entries in table, see code example below). Does this have to do with using InnoDB – would the results differ otherwise?

What is the advantage of using a transaction if 
1) I cannot rollback commited changes and 
2) I could just as well not commit changes (until I am done with my task or sure that some query didn’t raise any exceptions)?

I have tried to find the answers to those questions in https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/connector-python-en.a4.pdf but failed to find the essential difference.

Somebody asked an almost identical question and received some replies but I don’t think those actually contain an answer: [Mysql transaction : commit and rollback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890966/mysql-transaction-commit-and-rollback) Replies focused on having multiple connections open and visibility of changes. Is that all there is to it?

```
import mysql.connector

# Connect to MySQL-Server
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='test', password='blub',
                              host='127.0.0.1', db='my_test')
cursor = conn.cursor(buffered=True)

# This is anyway the default in mysql.connector
# cursor.autocommit = False

sql = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_test`.`employees` (
  `emp_no` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`emp_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8"""
try:
    cursor.execute(sql)
    conn.commit()
except:
    print("error")

# Arguments on default values
# conn.start_transaction(consistent_snapshot=False,
#         isolation_level=None, readonly=False)

sql = """INSERT INTO `my_test`.`employees`
(`first_name`)
VALUES
(%s);"""

employees = {}
employees["1"] = ["Peter"]
employees["2"] = ["Bruce"]
for employee, value in employees.items():
    cursor.execute(sql, (value[0],))
    print(conn.in_transaction)

# If I do not commit the changes, table is left empty (whether I write
# start_transaction or not)
# If I rollback the changes (without commit first), table is left empty
# (whether I write start_transaction or not)
# If I commit and then rollback, the rollback had no effect (i.e. there are
# values in the table (whether I write start_transaction or not)
conn.commit()
conn.rollback()
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance! I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think having not committed nor rolled back leaves the transaction in a running state, in which it may still hold resources like locks etc

Answer (score 0):

Your decision to have a transaction should take into account the numerous reasons for having one, including having multiple statements each of which commits writes the database.

In your example I don't think it makes a difference, but in more complicated scenarios you need a transaction to ensure ACID.

Answer (score 0):

Well it doesn't matter which db you are using when you call a transaction ,it will lock the resource (I.e any table) until the transaction is completed or rolled back for example if i write a transaction to insert something to a table test the test table will be locked until the transaction is completed this may leads to deadlock since others may need that table...You can try it on yourself just open two instances of your mysql in the first instance run transaction without commit and in the second try to insert something on the same table ...it will clear your doubt

Answer (score 0):

Transactions prevent other queries from modifying the data while your query is running.  Furthermore, a transaction scope can contain multiple queries - so you can rollback ALL of them in the event of an error, whereas that is not the case if some of them run successfully and only one query results in error, in which case you may end up with partially committed results, like JLH said.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I have to disagree though - and that is
exactly part of my confusion. A transaction should "bundle" statements into something atomic. So if I have to run 3 sequential statements (e.g. INSERT INTO) and the second one fails, I don't want any changes in my table/DB (**all or nothing**).
**BUT**: This is exactly what happens if I just run the three statements
without declaring them a transaction and only commit when all three have finished successfully.

Comment: See the code above. There are two data changing statements (cursor.execute).
Both are applied if and only if I commit. Whether I explicitly write
start_transaction or not. If I check for exceptions/errors and the second
statement raises an exception, I could just refrain from commit. No data would be written to the table. Although I would not (explicitly?) bundle the statements as a transaction, they are "quite" atomic.

Maybe my confusion comes from autocommit being _on_ by default in MySQL but _off_ by default in mysql.connector for python.

Comment: Ahhh - good feedback - I wonder if that's it!  Please update with a comment once you find out.  Regarding the bundling - transactions are good practice because it's explicit and isn't dependent on other variables (like default settings, number of statements, etc.) - and while it may not matter in this simple example, it could become problematic in more complex scenarios!

Comment: @ThomasE Any luck?

Comment: I did test it a bit more. Not sure if this is a full explanation. If autocommit is _on_ (in the code above `conn.autocommit = True`), a cursor.execute gets commited automatically as expected. So, similiar behavior with mysql.connector in Python as if you ran a single SQL statement in MySQL Workbench. 
If autocommit is _off_ as it is by default using mysql.connector, all SQL statements/executes are commited only when explicitly commited (`conn.commit()`). Thus, with mysql.connector statements are automatically/by default transactions-like in the sense of bundling/atomicity.

Comment: Most likely transactions are useful in mysql.connector for all the reasons you and others mentioned (like visibility of changes within/between transactions) but I only care for atomicity as I only have one connection. Thus, I will stick with autocommit _off_ and commit only when all executes ran successfully (i.e. without raising exceptions).